# permission denied for chmod as root

Tags: permissions, root, openvz

I need to manage a customer's openvz guest (latest debian squeeze 64 bit). Now when I try to do a `chmod 0750 /root` as root it gives me `Permission denied`. This really puzzles me, as I thought root can do *everything*.

As far as I can tell there's no selinux running (is this possible at all in an openvz guest?). I looked into some logfiles (syslog, kern, dmesg) and didn't see any messages.

How can find why root is unable to `chmod 0750 /root`?

Update: It's even more weird as I also cannot create any files in /root. `mkdir: cannot create directory '/root/test': Permission denied`

Comment: Did you have SElinux enabled ? Maybe disabling or set to "permissive" the time to change/create whatever you need to.

Comment: As I wrote: "As far as I can tell there's no selinux running (is this possible at all in an openvz guest?). I looked into some logfiles (syslog, kern, dmesg) and didn't see any messages.". How can I see if SElinux is enabled?

Comment: As a side note, you can make mounts read-only inside containers by doing `mount --bind -r /old /new` on the HN (see http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I just found out the directory was marked as "immutable" as can be checked with `lsattr`. After doing a `chattr -i /root` everything works now as expected :)

Comment: Simply helpful!